# iOS: Detect Keyboard Input globally

Tags: ios, swift

If my app is not used for a certain amount of time I want to logout my user. For touch interaction I could override sendEvent on UIWindow. But for keyboard input it does not work.

Is it possible to receive an event whenever the user uses the keyboard? (I do not want to subclass UITextField etc. as I also have WebViews in my app).

Comment: You could consider a singleton that observers keyboardShow and hide notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `hitTest` for `UIWindow` - it handles also system keyboard touches:

```
extension UIWindow {
    override open func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        print("touched!")

        return super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the better way for you to disconnect the user is by using either `func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication)` or `func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication)`.

To be prevent of the user interaction with the keyboard, you can implement `UITextFieldDelegate`, with by instance the following function which could allow you to know when the user has typed a character, the last time: `func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool`.